# overlay 2 textview in one linear layout

Tags: android, kotlin

Is it possible to overlay 2 textviews in one linear layout? I want them in the same position but they have to be in one linear layout

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">

            <Textview
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
               <Textview
                android:id="@+id/tv2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Linear layout there if you want it to be overlapping .. you can use RelativeLayout or FrameLayout

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="asdf"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="sfgsfg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

sadly they can't in `LinearLayout`, but you can use `FrameLayout` - without an easy option for placing child `View`s next to each other (as in `LinearLayout`) - or `RealtiveLayout` - which have some params for [placing one `View` next to/above another](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative#Position) when needed

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <Textview
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        
    <Textview
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```